# Trying to find a way to take a series of values in a json array and add them to an int

Tags: php, arrays, json

Here is my PHP function that grabs data from inputs on the page.

```
function getCounts($selection, $srch) {
    $loadjson = file_get_contents('data.json');
    $jsondata = json_decode($loadjson);
    $total = 0;
    foreach ($jsondata as $list) {
        if ($list->$selection == $srch) {
            $total .= $list->TOTAL
        }
    }
    echo 'Total - ' . $total . '<br>' . '<br>';
}
```

I know the issue is with the line "$total .= $list->TOTAL" but I cannot figure out how to take the value that "$list->TOTAL" gets and add it to an integer. I have tested and if I do "echo $list->TOTAL . ','" instead of "$total .= $list->TOTAL" the function spits out a list of all the numbers that are in the JSON data I simply cannot figure out how to get the numbers into an integr and added into one number.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Hi Xionous. Welcome to stackoverlfow! I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to do -- it might be helpful to also include what the output looks like, and what you want it to look like. But `json_decode()` might be what you're looking for (it turns a json object into a php object or array) https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_json_decode.asp

Comment: Hi, I am already using json_decode. The array has a series of entries with a key of "total" and a number value. My code iterates through these entries and what I want is to add up all of the numerical values of the key labeled total.

Comment: Oh -- in your code you have `$total .= $list->TOTAL`. You're concatenating the values. Use `$total += $list->TOTAL;`